# crash when calling gd function

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, gd, visual-c++-2010

I got libgd from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gd.htm) and link to it from within some MSVC 2010 project. When I call `gdImageCreateFromPng(FILE *in)`, it crashes. I'm not exactly sure where to start debugging so I'm asking here. Maybe the libgd is outdated (it's from 2005)? Maybe it is something unrelated?

Comment: Albert: Comments are not required with down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched a bit around and it was said [in this forum post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/479025-libgd-problem/) that the published DLLs are compatible to MSVC6 only. Esp., it is said there that all gd-functions which take a `FILE*` parameter don't work.